# Terminology request: the name of such functions

Tags: reference-request, terminology

Suppose $S$ is a finite set,  define function $f: 2^S \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^+$, that is, a function from subsets of $S$ to positive real numbers. Also, for any disjoint $X,Y \subseteq S$ we have following three properties:
$$f(X\cup Y)\le f(X)+f(Y)$$
$$f(X\cup Y) = f(\{X\})+f(Y)$$
$$f(X\cup Y) \ge f(X)+f(Y)$$

Is there any terminology to discribe $f$ if it satisfies the three properties respectively? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you want to put some conditions on the value of $f$ on larger sets, too? Perhaps relating $f(X\cup Y)$ to $f(X)$ and $f(Y)$ when $X$ and $Y$ are disjoint?

Comment: @ChrisCulter Yes, I'm also considering the general case. I'll revise my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second condition (assuming you meant $f(X \cup Y) = f(X) + f(Y)$) is usually called additivity (compare to $\sigma$-additivity for measures). The others might be termed "subadditivity" and "superadditivity", respectively, but I haven't seen them before.

Comment: They occur in fuzzy measure theory
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuzzy_measure_theory